# Changing class of a variable when subclassing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

I have a simple class defined, called 'PostView', which subclasses UIView. Inside that class I have defined an 'item' in the implementation, which is an instance of 'Post'.

```
@interface PostView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
  Post *item;
}
```

This works fine for me, but a problem occurs when I subclass it: 'PostPhotoView'. The 'item' variable now needs to be a 'PostPhoto' instance, but I'm not sure how I can go about doing this without defining 'item' in each subclass, which sound a bit repetitive and dirty..

Ideally I want to do this:

```
@interface PostPhotoView : PostView {
  PostPhoto *item;
}
```

But obviously I cannot redefine the variable. Maybe I am going about this in the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: PostPhoto means PostPhotoView class right ? remove item instance from postView class. You already declared item in postphotoView.

Comment: No, `PostPhoto`. `PostPhotoView` extends from `PostView`. `PostPhoto` extends from `Post`. All subclasses of `PostView` will have an item, and each item will subclass `Post`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to deal with this:

- Typecast your access to the ivar/property: `PostPhoto *theItem = (PostPhoto *)self.item`
- Declare the ivar (or the return type of the accessor) as type `id`, so you can do `PostPhoto *theItem = self.item`. For completeness, if you’re using a declared property of type `id`, you might also want to check the value in the setter: `NSParameterAssert([theItem isKindOfClass:[Post class]])`.